# github insights: how to look for commits of a specific branch

Tags: github

Under insights -> commits, I see graph (number of commits X date) for each developer for master branch.
But I want to track this for "develop" branch. How can I?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [git shortlog](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-shortlog) on any given branch to show the username and the number of created commits with:

```
shortlog -sn --no-merges
```

you can also add the `--since=<date>` flag like:

```
git shortlog -sn --no-merges --since="Nov 1 2020"
```

There are many more flags available [follow the link](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-shortlog) to read the documentation.

Comment: Thanks Can I look this up on my project portal?

Comment: I don't know what your project portal is @mobileDev but you can look it up on your command line and then you could have a cloud service looking it up and doing with it what ever you like

Comment: project portal should be same (almost) for any github project. Looking for the ways to monitor historical contribution of team members to the project. Thanks